# Sending curl-Request with a spoofed IP AND catching response on other client?

Tags: php, curl

basicaly i'd like to know, if there is any way to "fake" the http-handshake by doing something like this:

1. SERVER1 sends a HTTP-Request width IP of CLIENT1 to SERVER2
2. SERVER2 receives the request and answers to the submited IP
3. CLIENT1 receives the answer from SERVER2

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is, thankfully, not possible due to the [TCP Handshake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Connection_establishment) that occurs:

> To establish a connection, TCP uses a three-way handshake. Before a
>   client attempts to connect with a server, the server must first bind
>   to and listen at a port to open it up for connections: this is called
>   a passive open. Once the passive open is established, a client may
>   initiate an active open. To establish a connection, the three-way (or
>   3-step) handshake occurs:
>
> 1. SYN: The active open is performed by the client sending a SYN to the server. The client sets the segment's sequence number to a random
>      value A.
> 2. SYN-ACK: In response, the server replies with a SYN-ACK. The acknowledgment number is set to one more than the received sequence
>      number i.e. A+1, and the sequence number that the server chooses for
>      the packet is another random number, B.
> 3. ACK: Finally, the client sends an ACK back to the server. The sequence number is set to the received acknowledgement value i.e. A+1,
>      and the acknowledgement number is set to one more than the received
>      sequence number i.e. B+1.
>
> At this point, both the client and server have received an
>   acknowledgment of the connection. The steps 1, 2 establish the
>   connection parameter (sequence number) for one direction and it is
>   acknowledged. The steps 2, 3 establish the connection parameter
>   (sequence number) for the other direction and it is acknowledged. With
>   these, a full-duplex communication is established.

So while you could initiate a request to a server with a fake source-ip; the SYN that the server sends to complete the initialization will not be SYN-ACK'ed by that fake IP